# Import from subpackage or full path difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, global-variables, global

Importing the same Python module from a different path appears to result in the creation of two different module references.

For example take the following three Python scripts. Script1 and Script2 are located in OuterPackage, TestWithGlobals is located in SubPackage.

```
+ Root
|_+ OuterPackage
  | - Script1
  | - Script2
  |_+ SubPackage
    | - TestWithGlobals
```

Script1:

```
from OuterPackage.SubPackage import TestWithGlobals
import Script2
print TestWithGlobals.__name__

print TestWithGlobals.global_string
Script2.MakeStringBall()
print TestWithGlobals.global_string
```

and Script2:

```
from SubPackage import TestWithGlobals
print TestWithGlobals.__name__

def MakeStringBall():
    TestWithGlobals.global_string = "ball"
```

and finally TestWithGlobals itself

```
global_string = "test"
```

Now, when Script1 is run the output is as follows:

```
SubPackage.TestWithGlobals
OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals
test
test
```

Changing `from SubPackage` to `from OuterPackage.SubPackage` in Script2 will result in different output for Script1:

```
OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals
OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals
test
ball
```

Root is appended to the pythonpath before running Script1.

Why is TestWithGlobals different between Script1 and Script2, while the same module is referenced? What is the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code as follows it tells a little more of what's going on:

Script1.py

```
import sys
from OuterPackage.SubPackage import TestWithGlobals
print "In Script1", id(sys.modules['OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals'])
import Script2
print TestWithGlobals.__name__

print "TestWithGlobals:", TestWithGlobals.global_string
Script2.MakeStringBall()
print "TestWithGlobals:", TestWithGlobals.global_string
print "Script2.TestWithGlobals:", Script2.TestWithGlobals.global_string
```

Script2.py

```
from SubPackage import TestWithGlobals
print TestWithGlobals.__name__
import sys

def MakeStringBall():
    print "In MakeStringBall", id(TestWithGlobals)
    print "In MakeStringBall Subpackage.TestWithGlobals", id(sys.modules['SubPackage.TestWithGlobals'])
    print "In MakeStringBall OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals", id(sys.modules['OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals'])
    TestWithGlobals.global_string = "ball"
```

The output of this is:

```
In Script1 4301912560
SubPackage.TestWithGlobals
OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals
TestWithGlobals: test
In MakeStringBall 4301912784
In MakeStringBall Subpackage.TestWithGlobals 4301912784
In MakeStringBall OuterPackage.SubPackage.TestWithGlobals 4301912560
TestWithGlobals: test
Script2.TestWithGlobals: ball
```

The import system in python constructs new modules and references them via their import path in the `sys.modules` cache.  In this case the modules get imported under 2 different paths so 2 different module objects are created (as you can see by the output of the id functions).